# What type of __iter_concept<_Iter>

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I watched `std::random_access_iterator` and other iterator concepts 
This is what the GCC implementation looks like

```cpp
template<typename _Iter>
    concept random_access_iterator = bidirectional_iterator<_Iter>
      && derived_from<__detail::__iter_concept<_Iter>,
              random_access_iterator_tag>
      && totally_ordered<_Iter> && sized_sentinel_for<_Iter, _Iter>
      && requires(_Iter __i, const _Iter __j,
          const iter_difference_t<_Iter> __n)
      {
    { __i += __n } -> same_as<_Iter&>;
    { __j +  __n } -> same_as<_Iter>;
    { __n +  __j } -> same_as<_Iter>;
    { __i -= __n } -> same_as<_Iter&>;
    { __j -  __n } -> same_as<_Iter>;
    {  __j[__n]  } -> same_as<iter_reference_t<_Iter>>;
      };
```

How is it that `__iter_concept<_Iter>`, derived `from random_access_iterator_tag` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it that `__iter_concept<_Iter>`, derived from `random_access_iterator_tag`?

Because it's written to be. `__iter_concept` is not a concept; it's a *type* (or type alias). C++20 specifies a set of rules for determining the iterator category (forward, random access, input, etc) from a valid iterator that implements the C++20 `concept`-ified iterator category. The name for these rules is confusingly named "[ITER_CONCEPT](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/iterator.concepts.general)".

The word "concept" here is to denote that it is using the C++20 concept rules for this computation, not the C++17 pre-concepts rules.

`__detail::__iter_concept<T>` is the template metaprogramming type in your GCC standard library that implements ITER_CONCEPT. Hence the name. It generates a type that is inherited from the ITER_CONCEPT-defined type, so that the concepts that use it can use `derived_from` to detect the iterator type.

Comment: I know this is not a concept.
I was wondering how it turns out that it is derived from random_access_iterator_tag, if the iterators themselves are not explicitly inherited from it

Comment: @dodickgod: It's template metaprogramming. It computes a type in accord with the ITER_CONCEPT rules.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try to trace the path of getting the type.
As I understood, it can only be contiguous_iterator_tag or random_access_iterator_tag.
I think I understood the purpose of std:: derived_from in this situation

Comment: @NicolBolas As a side question, any idea why it says :`{ __j +  __n } -> same_as<_Iter>;`? Shouldn't be `{ __j +  __n } -> same_as<const _Iter>;` considering `__j` is `const`?

Comment: @Afshin: The return value of a function being `const` doesn't matter.

Comment: @NicolBolas What do you mean? I thought `{ __j +  __n } -> same_as<_Iter>;` means that `+` operator is defined and it returns an iterator. But when we add to a `const` iterator, we should get a `const` iterator as a result, isn't it? so why return value being `const` does not matter? if we think of it as something like this: `_Iter func_add(const _Iter iter, int n) { _Iter it = iter; return it + n; }` it will be invalid for an `const` iterator I think, because after adding to `const` iterator we need to get `const` iterator, not non `const` one.

Comment: @Afshin: "*we should get a const iterator as a result, isn't it?*" Should we? If I add two integers together, does it change the type of the result if one of them is non-modifiable? If I add two strings together, does it matter to the result if one of them is non-modifiable? You are not getting a *reference* to `__j`; you are getting a *copy* of it which has been modified. Why should the copy be non-modifiable?

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah...got it. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols starting with `__` or `_Capital` are reserved for your c++ compiler and std library to use for internal implementation details.  (Use of such symbols anywhere else is banned by the standard, unless allowed by your compiler explicitly).

So that template is some internal implementation detail used to implement the C++ standards requirements for that concept.

```
__detail::__iter_concept<_Iter>
```

this is the std library internal implementation's way to get a tag for a given type.  It is probably defined elsewhere in the std headers as C++ code.  How it works, I would read the source code.  Or rather, I would just presume it does what it says.

The naive method would just be to use the std `iterator_traits`.